# Difference between purist's and pragmatist's model of programming

Tags: java

While reading the introduction I came across this line in the book "Java The Complete Reference" by Herbert Schildt.

> Java manages to strike a balance between the purist's "everything is an object" paradigm and the pragmatist's "stay out of my way" model. The object model in java is simple and easy to extend, while primitive type, such as integer, are kept as high performance non objects.

Now I know that Java is purely object oriented so in Java everything can be considered as an object but I have no idea about the other model.

Comment: Do you consider `int` to be an object-type?

Comment: @akuzminykh Well I come from Python background where int is an object so naturally I assumed it to be an object in JAVA  as it is mentioned as pure object oriented language by my teacher ( an online course on YouTube) but the paragraph mentioned in question perplexed me.

Comment: Primitives (int, long, float, double, boolean) are *not* objects. They are purely primitive values. Java is not purely object oriented.

Comment: The quote in your own question says *"primitive type, such as integer, are kept as high performance **non objects**"* (emphasis mine), so there is your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python an integer is an object and it has methods.

```py
x = 1
y = x.__add__(2)
print(y) # 3
```

The variables `x` and `y` just hold references to objects. (You can just write `x + 1` of course.)

In Java integers are *primitives*. They are not objects that represent a value; they are the values themselves. (Java also has an object-type, or *reference*-type, for integers but that's not the topic.) The type `int` has no methods.

```java
int x = 1;
int y = x + 2;
System.out.println(y); // 3
```

So in regard of your question:

> [...] Java is purely object oriented so in Java everything can be considered as an object [...]

This is simply not correct as you can see from the example above. This is what the book talks about: While Java is object-oriented it also supports primitive data-types like `int`. It is less expensive to manage a value directly than managing an object, which makes sense, as a processor works with values, or rather numbers, and not with objects.

The idea behind the pragmatist's "stay out of my way" model mentioned in the book is just that: When you work with integers, you want to work with values. Why would one want to put object-orientation in-between, even giving up performance just for purism?